# What is the timing to load video in HTML

Tags: html, video, browser

I was writing a web page that shows an overlay div when user click on buttons.
One of the overlay div automatically plays video when it shows up, others just show picture. Below is part of the Jade code.

```
div.overlay#video-content
    div.video
        video#vid-name(controls loop)
            source(src="/video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4")
div.overlay#pic-content
    div.pic-1
        img.des(src="/images/picture-1.png")
```

In the "Network" page of Google Developer Tool, it just shows the time and file size of HTML, CSS, JavaScript and Image files.
Although the page can play the video when that div shows up, **the Developer Tool doesn't show when and how long browser takes to load the video file**.

I'm wonder when does the browser get the video content. I believe there is no way for a browser to play this video without getting the resource from server.

P.S. I've tried using ctrl+F5 to force browser to request server for every resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your server supports byte range requests then the browser will generally request the video in 'chunks' and start playback as soon as it had enough info to begin.

A standard MP4 file has its metadata at the end, however, which means the video can't start until it has downloaded all the chunks.

You can modify the MP4 to move the metadata to the front to enable better streaming using various tools - see here for more info on one, qt-faststart:

- https://multimedia.cx/eggs/improving-qt-faststart/

If you want even better user experience, then you probably want to use a dedicated video streaming server which supports adaptive bit rate streaming - this creates multiple size versions of the video from low to high quality and the browser request the next chunk from the size file which best meets the current network conditions.

If you go this way then you most likely will be better off using an existing video streaming server, rather than trying to recreate this functionality yourself. An example of open source streaming server is:

- https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't receive the notification that you've reply this problem.